# Spring mvc change the src of the image. How make it stable?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Hi  i am currently facing this problem:
i am using spring mvc controller which responce with the image for this address:
"photo/menu/{id}/small". But the thing is: when i am trying to display this image in the view like this:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/photo/place/${place.id}/small">,
```

in browzer it looks little different, somehow the src have changed, from

> /photo/place/${place.id}/small

it have become

> /photo/photo/place/${place.id}/small

: how can i fix this without changing the request path in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${pageContext.request.contextPath} returns you the additional "photo" path but i cant say why since i don't know how you deploy it, it looks like your app name is "photo" and your controller maps path to "place" and you manully try to put whole mapping but these are only my guesses
on the other hand you can try relative mapping like

```
<img src="../photo/place/${place.id}/small">
```

or

```
<img src="../../photo/place/${place.id}/small">
```

the path depends on the depth of your controller mapping

i mean that if you are in address lets say wwww.example.com/some/mapping and you want to insert here an image from www.example.com/resources/images/image.png then you map src path like

```
<img src="../resources/images/image.png">
```

I could say more if you add your controllers code